# How to change parametric object attributes after creation

Tags: modeling

Once a cylinder is created, how to go back to its attributes ?
"Vertices, Cap Fill type etc.."

Answer (score 0):

You will have one opportunity to adjust the parameters on the newly created object by pressing F6 blender 2.79b or the lower right properties box in 2.8. If you later on need to adjust it, just redo the object.

Comment: Strange... F3 for me in 2.79b is repeat history